# Exclude Tags from PHP Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written the following query in my child themes `functions.php` file.

Currently this works exactly as it needs to however I wish to extend this query such that it excludes specific tags.

```
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
           'terms' => 492,
           'field' => 'id',
      ),
   ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'compare'  => 'NOT IN'`.

```
'post_type'      => 'product',
'meta_key'       => 'total_sales',
'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
       'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
       'terms'    => array( 492, 422 ),
       'field'    => 'id',
       'compare'  => 'NOT IN'
    ),
),
```

USEFUL LINKS

- [wp_meta_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/)

Comment: Hi @Bhautik, so the product has both the 492 and 422 tag ID however I wish to exclude any products with the 422 tag ID from the query. Can you amend your code to reflect this and please elaborate on your changes?